# Cannot get Express to find routes

Tags: node.js, express

I am working on making adjustments to teammates code and I haven't been able to understand how they have done their routing. I am attempting to have Express run a middleware script when an end-user goes to a new session of the web application.

I don't know what to test next to figure out how they have done their routing.

Main.js

```
// Dependencies
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
var cors = require('cors');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Configuration
var config = require('./config');
var twilio = require('twilio');
// Database
mongoose.connect(config.database);
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function(){
    console.log('Connected to database');
});

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

// Setup middleware
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(cookieParser(config.sessionSecret));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use(busboy());
app.use(cors({
    origin: true,
  credentials: true
}));
app.all('/*',function(req,res){
    twilio.notifyOnSession();
    console.log('Message Sent');
})


var server = http.createServer(app);

var port = app.get('port');
server.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port ' + port);

// Load server router
require('./router')(app);
```

/router/index.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function(app){
  console.log('Initializing server routing');

  require('./auth')(app);
  require('./api')(app);

  // Determine if incoming request is a static asset
  var isStaticReq = function(req){
    return ['/auth', '/api', '/js', '/css'].some(function(whitelist){
      return req.url.substr(0, whitelist.length) === whitelist;
    });
  };

  // Single page app routing
  app.use(function(req, res, next){

    if (isStaticReq(req)){
      return next();
    }
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
  });
};
```

Comment: `isStaticReq` is useless; static requests were already handled by your static middleware.

Comment: Are you getting 404s or other HTTP error codes?

Answer (score 0):

Your `app.all('/*'` is swallowing all requests before they can hit your router.

Don't do that.

Comment: The `app.all('/*'` was an attempt to actually get the route and was unsuccessful

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by creating a new route with `twilio.js` and having the router look for the url `twilio/new`. Thanks all for the help.